# adding style to LinkButton without overriding css

Tags: asp.net, css, linkbutton

So it looks like if I add style such as background color to LinkButton in my .cs code, it overrides any css I have that applies to it.

is there any way to add style rather than replace it in my code behind? Thanks!
I am using link button as a menu, so active linkButton should have different background color.
so my solution was when the user clicks on the link button in my event handler I do something like:

```
   lnkView.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#369");
```

But then my hover style which I have in my css will no longer work:

```
.navlist a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #369;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

in my aspx:

```
<ul class="navlist">
        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server">view</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCreateNew" runat="server">create new</asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Your question is unclear, but you appear to be mis-understanding CSS.  Adding `background-color` to the `style` property will not cause it to completely ignore any CSS rules.  Rather, it will override any CSS rules for the `background-color` property, but will not affect any other rules.

If you don't want to override the `background-color` property from the CSS rule, add the `!important` flag to the CSS rule in `:hover`, like this:

```
background-color: #369 !important;
```

Also, change the color so that the change wil be noticable.

Alternatively, you could add a new CSS rule for `.navlist a:link .Active` with your background color, then add the `Active` class in code.  (`lnkView.CssClass += "Active"`)

By the way, instead of calling `Color.FromName`, you should write `Color.FromArgb(0x33, 0x66, 0x99)`.

Answer (score 1):

Any inline styles will always override any inherited styles from the head of a document or an external css file.  The only other option would be to add a javascript function that overrides the style of the object after DOM ready or Window ready event.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your use here, as your question isn't real clear.  However this could be an option as well.

Have two css styles:

```
.navlistafteranaction a:link
    {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #123;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.navlist a:link
    {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #123;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Then in your code behind just switch your CSSClass:

```
lnkbtn.CssClass = "navlistafteranaction";
```

This would change the class to have whatever style you wanted after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you want different styles applied based on whether the linkbutton is being hovered over?  So, have the style you have but also have:

```
.navlist a:link
    {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #123;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

if you want a third color, for after a link is visited, define that with `a:visited.`  Is that what you're after?